# How to set the initial view to have navigation bar back button SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigationview

If I have two views HomeView() and ListView() normally I would have to click on the navigation link from the HomeView to go to the ListView, and inside the ListView() there would be a navigation bar back button which will allow me to go back to the HomeView. However if I set the startup view as ListView() neither the navigation view or the back button is there. So how can I set the initial view as ListView() but still containing the all the stuff from the navigation view?

```
struct HomeView: View{
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             NavigationView {
                  NavigationLink(destination: ListView()){}
             }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ListView: View{
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             List()...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct HomeView: View{
    @State var isPresented = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ListView(),
                    isActive: $isPresented,
                    label: {
                        Text("List View")
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ListView: View{
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("List")
        }
    }
}
```